# Ajax / XMLHttpRequest tracking using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest, trace

I know firebug can trace all the Ajax/XHR events on a page. But I need to prepare a tool which automatically tracks these calls on button clicks on an already existing webpage.

My webpage's HTML and JS structure are follows:

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="callButton" class=" call-btn " style="width: 30px;">Call</a>
```

JS:

```
scope: this,
id: 'callButton',
handler: function () {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: '/Ajax/getCall/callUser/',
        params: {
            userID: usr.id
        },
```

Can anyone suggest how to track this ajax calls with the help of another javascript or something? Basically i need to get what is called on button click, in this example: "/Ajax/getCall/callUser/". It should work with all buttons on my page as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add at start of your script this:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.oldSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (data) {
    // there you can log requests
    console.log("AJAX request was sent.");
    this.oldSend.call(this, data);
}
```

This creates copy of `send` method on `XMLHttpRequest` object and internal method replaces by method where you can log AJAX requests and this method call the internal method whitch send AJAX request.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fgp783rz/1

Comment: Thanks it works fine! Can I also ask is there a method to get the "url" part of the Ajax call?