# Tracking site XHR with Java

Tags: java, xmlhttprequest, htmlunit

Tried to use htmlUnit to send POST requests to communicate to server and met a tiny problem: target .php url is being changed from time to time 
(www123.example.net -> www345.example.net, etc.).  The only way to get new adress is to open site and check it's XHR requests, find one which goes to www???.example.net and then use this address to send POSTs.

So the question is: **is there a way to track XHR using htmlUnit or any other Java library**?

Comment: I think that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144203/ajax-xmlhttprequest-tracking-using-javascript/30144416#30144416 could help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need help you have to show your problem in more detail, provide some info about the web site you are requesting, show you code and try to explain what you expect and what goes wrong. Without this details we can only guess.

Looks like you should try to think about HtmlUnit more like a browser you can control from java instead of doing simple Http requests. Have a look at the simple samples on the [HtmlUnit web site](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) (the one at the bottoms is for you).

Try something like this (the same steps as the user of an ordinary browser does)
* open the url/page
* fill the various form fields
* find the submit button an click
* use the resulting page content

Usually HtmlUnit does all the stuff in the background for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You see, the problem is the site I need to get data from is heavily JavaScript-loaded so HtnlUnit doesn't feel well there. However site gets the data I need via XHR - it makes POST request, gets text data, parses it and then user can see it on the page. So I can avoid messing with JS-generated content just sending the very same POST-request and getting data from respond. I do know how to submit a form - to make proper request I sign in on the site, grab cookies and place them into request headers.

Comment: I see, as always there is a chance that we can fix the js problems in HtmlUnit. Please open an issue and provide as many details a possible but at least the page url and the error messages you get.